# Roslyn embedd content into assembly

Tags: c#, .net, resources, roslyn

Is it possiblem to embedd `content` into an assembly using roslyn? Embedding resources works great, but can't figure out how to add content. I add resources like this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(inputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml")))
{
    var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower()),
                () => File.OpenRead(file.ToLower()),
                true);

    resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);
}
```

And than pass it when emitting:

```
EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms, manifestResources: resourceDescriptions.ToArray());
```

But I don't now to add other type of `Build Actions`.

**EDIT**

The `content` must be loadable using `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);`.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, for testing purpose I add both, .xaml and .baml, but I still get the message,
that `testusercontrol.xaml` was not found.

Here is how I'm adding those files:

```
List<ResourceDescription> resourceDescriptions = new List<ResourceDescription>();

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(outputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".baml")))
{
    var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                string.Format("{0}.g.{1}", RootNamespace, Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower())),
                Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower()),
                () => File.OpenRead(file.ToLower()),
                true);

    resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);
}

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(inputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml")))
{
    var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                string.Format("{0}.g.{1}", RootNamespace, Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower())),
                Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower()),
                () => File.OpenRead(file.ToLower()),
                true);

    resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);
}

EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms, manifestResources: resourceDescriptions.ToArray());
```

Do I use a wrong `ressourceName` (With edit 3, this should be yes)?

**EDIT 3**

I think I got whats going wrong. There are no ressource directories created in inside of the assembly. That is how it should look:

[image: Resource sample 01]

And that is how it looks currently:

[image: Resource sample 02]

But how can i create those directories using roslyn?

**EDIT 4**

Ok, embedding the resources works with the following code:

```
string resourcePath = string.Format("{0}{1}.g.resources", outputPath, RootNamespace);
ResourceWriter rsWriter = new ResourceWriter(resourcePath);

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(outputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".baml")))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower());
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    rsWriter.AddResource(fileName, data);
}

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(inputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml")))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower());
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    rsWriter.AddResource(fileName, data);
}

rsWriter.Generate();
rsWriter.Close();

var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                string.Format("{0}.g.resources", RootNamespace),
                () => File.OpenRead(resourcePath),
                true);

resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);

EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms, manifestResources: resourceDescriptions.ToArray());
```

It is also visible in `ILSpy`:

[image: Resource sample 03]

But the message box, that `testusercontrol.xaml` could not be found is still existing. What am I doing additionaly wrong?

---

**EDIT 5 - SOLUTION**

It works now! Steps:

First: Add the resource under the namespace AND assembly name, in any other case roslyn makes some trouble:

```
// Add ressource under the namespace AND assembly
var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                string.Format("{0}.g.resources", RootNamespace),
                () => File.OpenRead(resourcePath),
                true);
resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);

if (RootNamespace != assemblyName)
{
    resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription(
                    string.Format("{0}.g.resources", assemblyName),
                    () => File.OpenRead(resourcePath),
                    true);
    resourceDescriptions.Add(resourceDescription);
}
```

Second: Add the resource as a stream:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(outputPath).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".baml")))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.ToLower());
    var data = File.OpenRead(file);
    rsWriter.AddResource(fileName, data, true);
}
```

Third: Be happy

Thank you all!

Comment: Why you have written your answer in your question . answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Either I completely misunderstood the question, or you are asking for a square triangle.

The difference between "content" and "resource" is that content lives outside of an assembly, and resource is embedded into assembly. `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent` cannot load resources, it can only load content.

Thus, what you are asking for is impossible in principle.

Comment: But MS is embedding `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent` this into it's `.g.cs` files. But I've never seen them in some `bin\debug` or `release` directory. So it must be loadable from inside of the assembly. Are there some other `Build Action` like `Page` I could use with `Roslyn`? Thank you a lot!

Comment: So, yes, you are right. Those get embedded as YourNamespace.g.resources which is itself a [resource container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew6azb7(v=vs.90).aspx) that contains al the xaml's compiled to [baml's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Application_Markup_Language)

Comment: Thanks for that quick response :) I edited my initial post and add some more details. I thing I'm using a wrong ressource name, but can't figure out how it should look like. Do you see an failures there? For testing purpose I added both, xaml and baml

Comment: Yep, good progress. I think that you need to create the .resource file as described in the first link in my comment above. You need to put your baml inside this file, finally add the file to the resource the same way you are doing it now, with the name YourNamespace.g.resources.

Comment: Ok, adding the resources works perfectly, but the error is still existing. What do I wrong now. Thank you for your patience :) (I edited my post)

Comment: @ AndrewSavinykh it is working now. I will edit my question and show the results there :) Thank a lot!