# Creating an executable file with an icon from another assembly

Tags: c#, system.drawing, csharpcodeprovider

I'm looking for a way to take an icon from an executable, and create a new executable (using **CSharpCodeProvider**) that uses this icon.

The first part is easy, I do it using:

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
```

The problems come when I want to "attach" the icon. I tried using:

```
compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = @"/win32icon:"
```

But this solution requires the icon to be written in a file and I'd like to avoid that (one of the reason being it's such a mess to save an icon with more than 16 colors...).

Is it possible to use the System.Drawing.Icon object in memory directly?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm trying to obtain a code that can compile C# code into an executable. This executable will have an icon that is only hold in memory (as an Icon object) and not in a file (as a .ico file).

Comment: You can c# application with roslyn ,search how build compile with roslyn and embed resources  like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969090/roslyn-embedd-content-into-assembly-solved

Comment: I read about Roslyn and made some test. I still can't figure out how to put an icon to the generated application without using a file.

Comment: If you have set icon to your application so it will save in a file ***.resx** in  your project .you can see it under **Properties** in **Solution Explorer** in your project in Visual studio  , by  double clicking this file *.resx. so when you want compile your  project with roslyn you must before create ***.resources** file from *.resx file and **embed** to your compilation . Visual studio do these work too when compilation.I will answer this .iam busy and I wrote by mobile unfortunately now ..

Comment: I don't want to compile my project with Roslyn, I want my project to compile stuffs using the icon extracted from another executable file. So the icon only exist in memory as an Icon object. I hope there is a way to embed the icon without writing a .ico file...

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/109347/extract-high-quality-icons-from-files-using-a-free-tool/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IconLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx) to save Icon

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");
MultiIcon mIcon = new MultiIcon();
SingleIcon sIcon = mIcon.Add("notepad");
sIcon.CreateFrom(icon.ToBitmap(), IconOutputFormat.Vista);
sIcon.Save(@"c:\notepad.ico");
```

And use that for `CompilerOptions`

More information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aaxe43f.aspx

Comment: Thank you mohsen. There are still quality issues with this lib. I'm investigating it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

In case anyone is looking to do the same thing, here is a method that brought the expected result (icon extracting with correct graphic quality).

I use [Tsuda Kageyu IconExtractor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26824/Extract-icons-from-EXE-or-DLL-files) in order to get the icon I want and convert it to Bitmap with the transparency.
Then I use the [IconLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx) suggested by @mohsen to write in icon as a .ico file and then embed it with the CompilerOptions.